# Converting strings to lists

Tags: python, string, list

I'm reading a lot of strings from a file in this format: `string = [4,1,0.20,26,0.00]` that I need to convert to lists.

I tried using `string.split()`, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended. I need to use the string as a regular list, for example when I have `string[2]` it will point to `0.20`.

Comment: Please try to add a runnable example and your expected output.

Comment: give some example of what the lines in the file looks like

Comment: `string` is a `list` in the first place. `strip` applies to _strings_.

Comment: I'm reading this from a file, so it's stored as a string in my variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> string = "[4,1,0.20,26,0.00]"
>>> parsed = ast.literal_eval(string)

>>> parsed
[4, 1, 0.2, 26, 0.0]
>>> parsed[2]
0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

If say this is your given string:

```
s = '4,1,0.20,26,0.00'
```

Then do this:

```
lst = s.split(',')
print(lst)
```

and `print(lst[2])` should give you `0.20`